# react-router getting 404 when writing URL manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple project. I am using createBrowserRouter and everything works well until i deployed my project. I write the url manually and it shows 404. The landing page is fine but the other page is 404 if accessed by writing url manually.

Here is my code:

main.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <HomePage />
  },
  {
    path: '/products',
    element: <ProductsPage />
  },
  {
    path: '/products/:cat',
    element: <CategoryPage />
  },
  {
    path: '/products/detail/:id',
    element: <ProductDetailPage />
  }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I tried making _redirects and fill it with:
`/*  /index.html  200`
on public and it doesnt work.

I tried making .htaccess and fill it with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

on public and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate using the UI, it works because routing is handled by JavaScript. When you manually navigate to the page, the server is looking for the resource that matches that URL - it doesn't find it, which is why you are getting a 404 error.

Your `/products` page for example when navigated to using your app and the UI, the `<ProductsPage />` component is rendered. However, when you enter the `/products` page manually, the server is looking for a physical file or route handler for it.

One way to solve this is to bootstrap your React application to always return `index.html`, which will handle the routing for you. The way to do this depends on your web server however. You haven't mentioned which web server you are using, but since you have a `.htaccess` file, try the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this helps